# save and view blob images how to do it?

Tags: javascript, php

I wrote a script in javascript that allows me to capture an image from the input file type. I turn it into url and save it. so far everything ok. when I try to

## Javascript

```
function values(a){

if (a.length>1){

var imgdata;
var oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("immagine").files[0]);
 oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
   imgdata = oFREvent.target.result;
   var params= "V1="+a[2]+"& V2="+a[3]+"& V3="+a[4]+"& V4="+a[5]+"& V5="+a[6]+"& V6="+a[7]+"& V7="+a[8]+"& V8="+a[9]+"& V9="+a[10]+"& V10="+a[11]+"& V11="+a[12]+"& V12="+a[13]+"& V13="+a[14]+"& V14="+a[15]+"& img="+imgdata;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

 }
};
      xhttp.open("POST", "./server/AggiuntaBhk.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send( params);
};
```

## php

```
include("../../connessione_db/db_con.php"); // Include il file di 
 connessione al database
 session_start();

   $v1=$_REQUEST["V1"];
   $v2=$_REQUEST["V2"];
   $v3=$_REQUEST["V3"];
   $v4=$_REQUEST["V4"];
   $v5=$_REQUEST["V5"];
   $v6=$_REQUEST["V6"];
   $v7=$_REQUEST["V7"];
   $v8=$_REQUEST["V8"];
   $v9=$_REQUEST["V9"];
   $v10=$_REQUEST["V10"];
   $v11=$_REQUEST["V11"];
   $v12=$_REQUEST["V12"];
   $v13=$_REQUEST["V13"];
   $v14=$_REQUEST["V14"];
   $foto=$_REQUEST["img"];
   $queryInput="INSERT INTO bhk (Metrica1,Metrica2,Metrica3,Metrica4,Metrica5,Metrica6,Metrica7,Metrica8,Metrica9,Metrica10,Metrica11,Metrica12,Metrica13,Data,Puntoz,Paziente,Foto) VALUES ('$v1','$v2','$v3','$v4','$v5','$v6','$v7','$v8','$v9','$v10','$v11','$v12','$v13','2014-01-01','$v14','BVNVCN97L18C983O','$foto')";

       $queryI = mysqli_query($connessione_al_server,$queryInput);
```

## query

```
   $queryi = "SELECT Foto  FROM bhk   WHERE Cod_Bhk = '".$Codice."'";
<h1>to Display</h1>
        <img id="imgcaricata" class="mySlides" src="'.( $foto["Foto"] ).'" style="height:auto; width:auto;max-width:500px; margin-top:55px;"/>
```

The image saved in the db is :

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAHgAeAAD/4QBoRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAEa ....... ecc
```

the Error is:

```
net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

"Foto" in the database is of type longblob

Comment: can you share the full text saved in db ?

Comment: It's too long. It won't let me put it in.

Comment: check whether any space between the base64 text

Comment: is it working ?